# Objective-C Distribute framework from Pod

Tags: ios, frameworks, cocoapods

This is my scenario:

I develop and manage a pod library that we use privately in our team. Now I need to distribute this framework to a third party hiding the implementation.

My pod:

- Depends on other pods
- Client will include all necessary frameworks into their project

My challenge:

An efficient way to generate a dynamic framework without linking these dependent frameworks so client can avoid any duplicate symbols warnings.

I've been researching, I found some interesting tutorials and threads here in SO about almost the same challenge as mine.

I would appreciate any help on pointing me into the right direction. Thanks in advance.